# android Java Multiple classes update activity UI (how to share data)

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked several times, but I cannot seems to find a suitable answer or there is multiple solutions. I am just trying to find were to look and the best possible solution.

I have an app that has several activities such as Main, Settings, User profile etc and I have different source for information coming into the app such as pulling data from a server, BLE comms, back ground timer etc. The plan would be to have these calling comms functions in separate classes i.e. servercomms, BLEStack, timer etc

The question what is the best way to share the data from these classes to the activity UI? There seems to be different methods such as Intent, Async, Runable but not sure which one should be used? When I look at one it seems create performance issues and will stop running if the device is short on memory.

For example if there is a Timer running in the background, which will update a picture, text on the Main Activity how can I call a function or update the UI from the timer class? I thought run a function in the MainActvity code, but not sure if that is correct as I read it might affect the mobile app performance?

Sorry, I know this question has been answered and I have followed each thread but just cannot work out the best way to make it all work with sharing data and updating the activity UI.

Comment: Use architecture components like `ViewModel` to persist & observe live changes from (activity or fragment) to data coming from a remote source or local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest having look at [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) as per their description:

*Event bus for Android and Java that simplifies communication between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc. Less code, better quality.*

**OR**

Have a look at the official android documentation [Communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) which shows how to use `ViewModel`s to share data between activities and fragments and fragment to fragment.